alphanumerics in duration in sheets - how to convert to a number of minutes
Working in google sheets, I am getting input from another program in the form of "Xh Ym Zs" to track time. I'm trying to write a formula that will just yield a number of minutes, so
"2h 22m 5s" would give 142.
I'm trying all sorts of things with find, search, regexmatch, but I'm running into 2 problems -- one is that there's no set number of characters in each category -- 1h 5m 40s instead of 01h 05m 40s. the other is that the input I'm getting just leaves out a category if it's a zero -- if a student was working for just 35 minutes, the program gives me '35m', not 0h 35m 0s. Similarly, a student who worked for 4 hours and 25 seconds yields '4h 25s'.
Is it even possible to do this with one formula?

Use regexextract(), like this:
=let( 
  get_, lambda(s, ifna(regexextract(A2, "(\d+)" & s), 0)), 
  duration, value(join(":", get_("h"), get_("m"), get_("s"))), 
  iferror(round(24 * 60 * duration)) 
)

See
let(),
lambda(),
ifna(),
regexextract(),
value(),
join(),
iferror(),
and
round().
For some background, see Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

THANK YOU! I have to learn my regular expressions. this works beautifully.

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See What should I do when someone answers my question?
